# How do I pass C# variable in JS

Tags: javascript, blazor

I want to create a chart and compare 2 values, I a using ChartJs .. now the issue is how do i pass the Binded result variable to the js , what i mean is how to remove the static values from chart and provide the c# values..

my blazor variables are PreMoney Value & PostMoney Value and how should I pass the PreMoney Value & Post Money Value in data:[]

```
 window.chartJs = () => {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                **data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],**
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
    var myVentureChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['PreMoney Value', 'PostMoney Value'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
                    
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
 };
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/ . Or maybe this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: You have already 4 questions for which you got answers but never gave any feedback. If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If there's still anything unclear in any answer, don't hesitate to ask the author. With zero feedback, the author never knows if the answer was helpful or not.

Answer (score 1):

In your Blazor page:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRunTime;

<div id="chartdiv"></div>

<button @onclick="CreateChart">Create Chart</button>

@code {
   private async Task CreateChart()
   {
      await jsRunTime.InvokeVoidAsync("YourJavaScriptFunction", preMoney,  postMoney);
   }
}
```

In your JavaScript:

```
function YourJavaScriptFunction(preMoney, postMoney) {
   ...
}
```